# How CPU generates logical addresses?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, virtual-memory, mmu

CPU generates logical addresses. These logical addresses then converted into physical addresses by special unit MMU. This is written in so many books including [Galvin](http://www2.latech.edu/~box/os/ch08.pdf) (slides 6-7).

But I want to know how CPU generates logical address and what does it mean?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. This site is about programming. Consider posting this question at serverfault.stackexchange.com maybe

Answer (score 1):

It is just a simplification.

CPU doesn't generate logical addresses. They are stored in your executable file. CPU reads your program and extracts these addresses.

[Here](http://www2.latech.edu/~box/os/ch08.pdf) (slide 7) Galvin says:

> In MMU scheme, the value in the relocation register is added to
>   every **address generated by a user process** at the time it is sent to
>   memory.
>
> The **user program deals with logical addresses**; it never sees the
>   real physical addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU does not generate logical addresses. Logical to physical address mapping is defined by the operating system. The operating system sets up page tables that define the mapping.

The processors defines structure of the page tables. The operating system defines the content of the page tables.